# Windows 10 Update 2004 breaks SQL connection

Tags: sql-server, windows, desktop-application

I have a few clients which are having issue with direct SQL connections after updating windows to the latest feature update 2004!

Basically the systems are able to open a telnet session fine on the 1433 so I am confident that its not a lower layer issue but applications like SSMS can't connect out!

I have even updated to KB4571744 to see if that helps but no..

My test system which I am using for diagnostics is running build 19041.488

My first set of tests have been trying to disable/override all the new security stuff but without any success.

Anyone seen this or know further diagnostic/fixes I could try?
Thanks,
Richard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! the issue was that the new 2004 update stops TLS below 1.2, understandably! The server we are connecting to happened to be a little old! Updated the server and all works fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

I added these keys for TLS 1.2 to my registry and SQL 2017 was back up...

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault "=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault "=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001